# RestKit: mapping nsnumber

Tags: objective-c, restkit

Currently NSNumber get mapped to string, e.g.:

@interface Blah : NSObject

@property NSNumber *num;

@end

will get mapped to 
{
    num: "5"
}

instead of 
{
    num: 5
}

Does anyone know how to correctly map NSNumber to int, and NOT string?

Update:

```
RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"num"]];

RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping objectClass:[MyClass class] rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodPOST];

[_manager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
```

Comment: How are you mapping it? Show the code, full input and full output.

Comment: updated, also tried addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@[@"num.intValue": @"num"]